# Objective c lost CIImage memory when converting to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimage, ciimage

I have the following code:

```
- (void)applySepiaFilter {
    // Set previous image
    NSData *buffer = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.mainImage.image];
    [_images push:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: buffer]];

    [_images push:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: buffer]];


    UIImage* u = [_images pop];
    CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:u.CGImage];//[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:fileNameAndPath];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"
                                  keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, image,
                        @"inputIntensity", @0.8, nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
    //UIImage *newImage =
    self.mainImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage];
}
```

Where _images is a stack:

```
#import "Stack.h"

@implementation Stack{
    NSMutableArray *stack;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self!=nil){
        stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)push:(id)obj{
    [stack addObject:obj];
}

-(id)pop{
    id lastObj = [stack lastObject];
    if (stack.count > 1) {
        [stack removeLastObject];
    }
    return lastObj;
}

-(NSUInteger)size{
    return stack.count;
}

@end
```

and self.mainImage is an UIImageView.

The first time I run the method I get the desired sepia filter. I believe it is not saving the self.mainImage.image correctly though because if I run the method twice in a row I get a blank image for self.mainImage.image and if I run it a third time I get a SIGABRT error.
I added a breakpoint and started to go through the code. I noticed that at the end of the first pass of the method self.mainImage.image is a CIImage *. This confused me since it should be a UIImage * (see image).[Screenshot during debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79aNK.jpg)

The other thing that worried me was I noticed that the buffer size was significantly smaller than it should have been on the second pass. This leaves me to believe that the image isn't being saved. Also during the second pass, the debugger says *imge is null. (see screenshot)[Debugging screenshot during second pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr9Hn.png)

Comment: Convert the image back to a `CGImage` and create the `UIImage` from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the mainImage.image isn't being saved correctly, it's that `UIImageView` -- as anything related to CoreGraphics -- uses its `UIImage`'s `CGImage`. In the [documentation for which](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/CGImage) we see

> If the UIImage object was initialized using a CIImage object, the value of the property is NULL.

So what you want to be doing here is making a `CGImage`-backed UIImage, and then getting rid of all the CoreImage data allocations; assign `self.imageView.image` to something like

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromCIImage:(CIImage *)ciImage {
    CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];    
    CGImageRef cgImage = [ciContext createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:[ciImage extent]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: DO NOT do this conversion in main thread, it costs a lof of time.